# Fabric JS, How To Make The Image SRC File Stretch Or Repeat To The Image Object?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

If I have an image say 500x500 as a file, let's call it sample.jpg and I then add an image object tot he canvas of say 1000x1000 the load in sample.jpg the image doesn't stretch or repeat to fit the 1000x1000 but rather it sits in the top left corner at 500x500 of the image object.

Is there a way to force the source image to stretch into the image object on the canvas so it fills the whole area? Don't really care about distortion on the image ratio, just want it to fit in the whole larger area. Either stretch it, or is there a way to just repeat the image until it fits in the whole container? - I am probably missing something in their documents here.

Example of what I mean, dark blue is the 1000x1000 container (fabric js image object) and red is 500x500 JPG that I want stretching or repeating into the whole of the blue area:

[image]

```
var image = fabric.Image.fromURL('<?php echo $object->url; ?>', function(oImg) {
                    oImg.set({
                        top:parseInt('<?php echo $object->top; ?>'),
                        left:parseInt('<?php echo $object->left; ?>'),
                        width:parseInt('<?php echo $object->width; ?>'),
                        height:parseInt('<?php echo $object->height; ?>'),
                    });
                      designerCanvas.add(oImg);
                      designerCanvas.renderAll();
                });
```

Comment: After adding the blue image, the source image(red image) should be resized to fit in the size of the blue image. Is this really you want to achieve?
Please share your code of how you are adding images to the canvas.

Comment: added the code where I load in the image from url. You can see there I set the width and height of the object how I need it, but because the image itself is smaller than that the object bounds are the right size but the image doesn't fill it. So the blue here is the object container and the red is the JPG which I need to stretch to fit the blue. So far the only solution I have is to make the JPG larger than the object container so it fully fits.

Answer (score 0):

The stretching is pretty straightforward (there's a few examples in the [docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setBackgroundImage))

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://your_image_url', 
canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    width: canvas.width,
    height: canvas.height,
    // Needed to position backgroundImage at 0/0
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
});
```

Or if you don't want it as a background image

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://your_image_url', function(oImg) {
  oImg.set({ scaleX: canvas.width/oImg.width, scaleY: canvas.height/oImg.height, 
left: 0, top: 0 });
  canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

Comment: no, don't want a background image, it's an image object by loading from url.

Comment: just set the scaleX/Y factors and make sure the image is positioned top left, I've added the code above

Comment: `fromUrl` does not work in mocked files.